# binding the shift key in .tmux.conf doesn't work

Tags: tmux

This is my `.tmux.conf` file, placed in the home directory.

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix S-a
bind S-a send-prefix
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

I am properly loading it with `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`. However, doing `shift+a` to initiate the prefix doesn't work.

However if I replace `S-a` with `C-a`, it'll work (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But you are aware that when you use `S-a` as prefix, you won't be able to type a capital A in the shell? Maybe tmux is preventing you from doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't and it's not a good idea, the shift key is by no way meant for that. Take a look in the `man tmux`, section `KEY BINDINGS` for the list of available keys. More info are available here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140010

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Run: (**WARN: Save your work in all sessions first**)

```
tmux kill-server
```

### Solution 2

In your `.zshrc`/`.bashrc` file, add the following line:

```
[ -z "${TMUX}" ] || tmux YOUR_COMMAND
```

e.g. `YOUR_COMMAND` = `set -g prefix S-a`.